# C# Crazy Foreach Behavior

Tags: c#

I wrote a little Program that takes Data from an open API. Generates Objects from those and compares those List of Objects with some Data from the Database also in an List of Objects

The Problem is that the foreach Loop is getting slower and slower with each Loop done.

As you will see i am no pro. I am still an beginner and i don`t find an solution for this.

Here a picture of what happens:

[image]

Many thanks for every hint.

Here my Code:

```
public static List<Player> comparePlayersWithDB(Boolean difference, List<Player> jsonPlayer, List<Player> dBPlayer)
{
    List<Player> result = new List<Player>();

    if (!difference)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Searching for new Players -- " + DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime());
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Searching for differences in Players -- " + DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime());
    }

    DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;

    double statPercent = 0;
    var count = jsonPlayer.Count;
    int playerCount = 0;
    int lastPlayerCount = 0;
    double multiplier = ((double)100 / count);
    int nextStep = 10;
    Console.WriteLine("  0% ...... -- " + DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime());

    foreach (Player currentJson in jsonPlayer)
    {
        playerCount += 1;
        //Message to User
        if (statPercent >= nextStep)
        {
            int secondsGone = (DateTime.Now - startTime).Seconds;
            if (secondsGone == 0)
            {
                secondsGone += 1;
            }
            int playersEachSecons = (playerCount - lastPlayerCount) / secondsGone;
            Console.WriteLine(" " + (int)statPercent + "% (" + playerCount + "/" + count + ")......Speed: " + playersEachSecons + " Player/Second -- " + DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime());

            lastPlayerCount = playerCount;
            nextStep += 10;
            startTime = DateTime.Now;
        }


        if (dBPlayer.Exists(x => x.Name == currentJson.Name))
        {
            if (difference)
            {
                //Check for differences
                Player inDB = dBPlayer.Find(y => y.Name == currentJson.Name);
                if (inDB.XP != currentJson.XP || inDB.RP != currentJson.RP || inDB.Guild != currentJson.Guild)
                {
                    result.Add(currentJson);
                }
            }
        }
        // If currentPlayer not exists
        else
        {
            //and we are looking only for new Players
            if (!difference)
            {
                result.Add(currentJson);
            }
        }
        statPercent += multiplier;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: My guess is that the matching items in both lists are roughly in the same locations.  That means that the further you move into the first list the longer your `Exists` method will have to iterate the second.  What you really want to do is create a look up for one of the lists so you have a fast way to find matches when you iterate the other.  That turns a O(N*M) algorithm into an O(N+M) where N and M are the sizes of the lists.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a lookup on `dBPlayer` before your `foreach` like this.

```
var playerLookup = dbPlayer.ToLookup(p => p.Name);
```

Then you can do

```
if (playerLookup.Contains(currentJson.Name))
{
    if (difference)
    {
        //Check for differences
        Player inDB = playerLookup[currentJson.Name].First();
        if (inDB.XP != currentJson.XP || inDB.RP != currentJson.RP || inDB.Guild != currentJson.Guild)
        {
            result.Add(currentJson);
        }
    }
}
```

This will perform faster than doing an `Exists` and then a `Find` on the `dbPlayer` list.  Alternatively if you know for sure that there will not be any duplicate names you can use `ToDictionary` instead.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `Exists`, the whole list of dbPlayers has to be looped through (in the worst case where there is no matching entry). Then, if there *is* a match, you call `dbPlayer.Find()`, which basically does the whole thing again. It would be better to make a call to `Find()` and save the result in a variable. If the variable is `null` there was no match, otherwise you already have the requested entry.

You still have the drawback that you risk looping through all values in `dbPlayer` each time, which will make the performance get worse the more entries `dbPlayer` has.

I would recommend converting the `dbPlayer` list to a `Dictionary`, where the `Name` of each list entry becomes the key of the dictionary, like so:

```
using System.Linq;
[...]
var dbPlayerDict = dbPlayer.ToDictionary(x => x.Name);
```

This will allow you to look up existing players with a call to `TryGetValue()` which has the same performance no matter how many entries have to be searched, making your code look something like this:

```
Player inDB;
if (dBPlayerDict.TryGetValue(currentJson.Name, out inDB))
{
    if (difference)
    {
        //Check for differences
        if (inDB.XP != currentJson.XP || inDB.RP != currentJson.RP || inDB.Guild != currentJson.Guild)
        {
            result.Add(currentJson);
        }
    }
}
```

In the case where multiple player can have the same name, you are better off with the `Lookup` class, as described in @juharr's answer.